# Azure custom domain for multiple azure services

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate, azure-web-app-service

I have multiple services on my azure account, and I like to to have only one custom domain. My goal is to have following mapping:

- someapp.azurewebsites.net -> mydomain.com:443/someapp
- someapp2.azurewebsites.net -> mydomain.com:443/someapp2
- somedb.database.windows.net -> mydomain.com:1433

Is that possible? Using subdomains and wildcard certificate is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

The demand you provided is not mapping custom domain to azure webapp, it just a [url rewrite](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32229.azure-create-an-url-rewrite-azure-web-app.aspx).

You can create [CNAME record](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain) to map your custom domains to each web app. Like below and when visit children url, it will be clearly.

```
someapp.azurewebsites.net -> someapp.mydomain.com:443
someapp2.azurewebsites.net -> someapp2.mydomain.com:443
```

For azure sql you could refer to this [article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/how-to-use-different-domain-name-to-connect-to-azure-sql-server/ba-p/1217805) to map to custom domain.